# How to replace many Spaces with one':'?

Tags: python, string, replace

The number of spaces is different for each row.How to replace many Spaces with one':'?

*******There are spaces in middle of name.example:

```
Angle Shift    J614
```

output: `Angle Shift:J614`    not `Angle:Shift:J614`

code:

```
configDir={}
configList=[]
for configs in config_info.split('\n'):
    configs=configs.strip() 
    if (configs.find(':')>0):
        continue 
    if (configs==''):
        continue
    configs=configs.replace(' ',':')
    configList.append(configs)
configDir['config']=configList
```

Output:

> ```
> 'HandlingTool::::::::::H552',
>
> 'Chinese:Dictionary::::H538',
>
> '4D:Standard:::::::::::R782', 
>
> 'Analog:I/O::::::::::::H550', 
>
> 'Angle:Shift:::::::::::J614', 
>
> 'Auto:Software:Update::ATUP', 
>
> 'Automatic:Backup::::::J545', 
>
> 'Background:Editing::::J616'
> ```

Data sample:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbyGU.png)

Comment: But what output do you need? Like `4D Standard      R782` should really become `4D:Standard:R782`, or do you want the single space unaltered, so `4D Standard:R782`?

Comment: yes , 4D Standard:R782

Answer (score 1):

regex is what you need:

```
import re

pattern = r" +"

text = 'HandlingTool          H552'

sub = re.sub(pattern=pattern, repl = ":", string=text)

print(sub) # HandlingTool:H552
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, for every row of your input file

```
out = ":".join(list(filter(None, inp.split(' '))))

inp =  'HandlingTool        H552'
out = 'HandlingTool:H552'
```